# Generate unique login string based on username + integer fails, why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, unique, race-condition

We are using this code in a Ruby on Rails 4.2 project to generate a unique username. The method below is an instance method of a User class and receives a name string and -if required to avoid collisions- appends an integer. It then returns a unique login to be used e.g. like

```
self.login = self.generate_unique_sane_login(self.name)
```

in a before_save hook or in a controller. In particular, this is called when a new user instance is created, after registration.

However, once in a while this function fails. This method returns a login that already exists, the database driver then throws a uniqueness violation exception (Postgres in this case) and the application throws a HTTP/1.1 500. Or it doesn't even do that, we have several duplicates in the database that were definitely created using this code but do not validate once loaded again. Those users are then unable to edit their profile.

We are not seeing multiple simultaneous (or almost simultaneous) user registration attempts in our logs when this happens so I don't think this is a race condition issue.

So: why does this happen? Am I missing something? What would be a better solution to generate a unique user login string?

```
 def self.generate_unique_sane_login(l)
    l = l.gsub(/\@.*$/, '')
    l = l.gsub(/[^A-Za-z0-9äöüÄÖÜß]/, '_')
    c = 1
    login = l
    conflicting_logins = self.where("LOWER(login) = LOWER(?)", login)
    until conflicting_logins.empty?
      login = "#{l}#{c}"
      conflicting_logins = self.where("LOWER(login) = LOWER(?)", login)
      c = c+1
    end
    login
  end
```

### Answers to comments

Thank you for your comments. Here are my answers.

- We already use uniqueness validator and it doesn't catch these duplicates for some reason. Other duplicates are caught (also all are caught in tests), and these exceptions are not repetable (meaning if we register the same login that threw an exception ten minutes later it works suddenly).
- I would prefer understanding existing code to refactoring the whole authentication process, so other gems or replacement code is not an option right now.
- Using random values as the integer part is an idea but makes the logins very long, which I would like to avoid since they are user visible. Using a counter *should* work, shouldn't it?

Comment: How about using the system time in milliseconds as the integer part? `Time.now.to_f*1000`

Comment: Have you seen the [`uniqueness`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness) Rails validation? On [Github](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/validations/uniqueness.rb).

Comment: Have you useing devise authendication gem?

Comment: I answered your comments above in the main question text. Thank you!